# How to deploy smart contract with raw transaction

Tags: solidity, transactions, ether, contract-deployment, raw-transaction

I want to deploy transaction with raw transaction without using hardhat or web3 method.

my code looks like this.

```typescript
// constructor params
const name = 'My Contract';
const symbol = 'MC';
const maxSupply = 500;
const baseURI = 'https://sample/link';

const jsonRpcProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(MUMBAI_URL);
const executer = new Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, jsonRpcProvider);
const executerAddress = await executer.getAddress();

const MyContractAbi = new ethers.utils.Interface(MyContract__factory.abi);
const constructorEncodedData = MyContractAbi.encodeDeploy([name, symbol, maxSupply, baseURI]);
const txData = hexlify(concat([MyContract__factory.bytecode, constructorEncodedData]));

const unserializedTx = {
    to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: txData,
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x1e8480', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x06fc23ac00', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x06fc23ac00', _isBigNumber: true },
    nonce: 28,
    type: 2,
    chainId: 80001
  };

const signedTx = await executer.signTransaction(unserializedTx);
const txResponse = await (await jsonRpcProvider.sendTransaction(signedTx)).wait();
```

when I send transaction, it does executed, but it doesn't seem to create contract.
my transaction result link is [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x35fcb343b59fbb4e10094ff13d9d3f7cb89775f3f11c4bd7c275df73499818c4).

I refer to 'deploy' method in @ethersproject, but I don't know why it doesn't work.
any ideas?

Comment: In order to deploy a contract 'to' has to be empty (not the zero address). In your example you are sending the contract bytecode to the zero address. Since the zero address is a regular account then anything send to it is just ignored.

Comment: after deleting 'to' property and increase gas Limit(2_000_000 -> 5_000_000), it works. Thanks!!

Comment: You should write the answer with those details, that way you can mark the question as resolved.

Comment: This is awesome!  It's fun and demystifying doing things in low-level ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comment, just delete 'to' property in unserializedTx